# Excluding specific files or folders from Aptana validators

Tags: javascript, validation, aptana

So, I've installed Aptana for Eclipse this morning and so far trying to disable validation on library files has consumed my entire morning without any kind of result.

I've seen the following related threads:

- [How to exclude specific folders or files from validation in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272237/how-to-exclude-specific-folders-or-files-from-validation-in-eclipse)
- [Exclude directories & subdirectories from validation in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495378/exclude-directories-subdirectories-from-validation-in-eclipse)

With Aptana, none of these answers actually help. For example, there is no Preferences --> Validation tab. There is only Preferences --> Aptana --> Validation, where you cannot add exclusion rules.

I need to disable validation for numerous library files, such as a minified jquery.js.

Even worse, any kind of error seems to make it impossible to run the application as it gives me a *"Your project contains errors, please fix them before running your application."*.

How come an obvious and mandatory (considering that many libraries are minified or simply not strictly validated) task like this one seems to be impossible to accomplish?

Comment: There is work being done on allowing a disabling of validation, but which run process prevents you from actually running while there are errors?

Comment: @Ingo Muschenetz, running an Android Application (ADT).

Comment: Hmmm. Okay. For the moment, (as you may have already done) I would suggest just disabling the validation altogether for that file type until there is a fix. I'm surprised ADT doesn't allow you to continue anyway even with errors like JDT does.

Comment: @IngoMuschenetz do you have any idea what the ETA is for this disabling feature? Also, how can I completely disable the validators?

Comment: ETA: not yet, as it wasn't thought of as a serious bug that impeded workflow. If you can file a bug with exact repo steps, that would be great. As for disabling validation, Preferences > Aptana > Validation and uncheck anything that applies. You may have to do a Project > Clean to remove old markers.

Comment: @IngoMuschenetz I disabled all the validators, did a complete clean and refresh and the errors are still there in the problems window. I'm thinking Eclipse for Android + ADT + Aptana just aren't made for each other.

Comment: Tom...can you give repo steps? 1) Create new Android project, 2) Add minified jquery.js to the project 3) See errors?

Comment: @IngoMuschenetz I apologize for it but I'm afraid I cannot anymore, I have switched to using Eclipse for web developers in combination with ADT. Thanks for the help though. Although the steps you mentioned seem about right.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like this feature is still not available in Aptana (and the associated bug ticket has vanished), but Ingo Muschenetz provided a workaround technique here:

https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-2131?focusedCommentId=195320

> This can currently be done using the following technique:
>
> 1. Right click on the file/folder
> 2. Select "Build > Exclude from Index"
> 3. Project > Clean > Selected Project
>
> Once the build is completed, the validation warnings will be gone."

It works for a project coded but not built within Aptana. However, since you're working on an Android project with ADT, it might or might not have an impact on your build; I couldn't find information on what this "Exclude from Index" actually does.