# How to exclude .java files from validation in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, validation, warnings

In my source tree have Java code which is automatically generated from XSD files. This code is full of warnings which is messing other legitimate warnings. How do I exclude such folders or packages from validation?

Have read several similar questions, but those suggest to exclude folders from appropriate validator types found in Preferences. However I can't find validator for .java files.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Sasa

Comment: Won't this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495378/exclude-directories-subdirectories-from-validation-in-eclipse

Comment: It doesn't help as offered validators are all others but not for Java.  E.g. DTD, HTML, JSP, XML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the feature 'ignore optional compiler problems' from the very latest eclipse milestone:

http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/S-4.2M6-201203151300/eclipse-news-M6.html

Might be a workaround possible without that, like putting the auto generated files in a different project. But what you want to do is exactly the intended use of that feature.

Comment: Yep. This feature was made exactly for this scenario. Its been long overdue.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/31585850/606662 for an answer with more detailed explanation plus screenshot.