# How to disable eclipse kepler's javascript validation

Tags: javascript, eclipse, validation

I am really really sick of the JavaScript validation from eclipse and it's so hard to get rid of.

I knew there are many people had been seeking a solution to totally disable the JavaScript validation, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495378/exclude-directories-subdirectories-from-validation-in-eclipse). But the solution I saw didn't work.

Currently I have cancelled `JavaScript builder` in `project->properties->Builders`.

I have `suspend all validators` in `project->properties->Validation`.

I have removed all the folders in `project->properties->JavaScript->source`

and yes, I have cleaned the project and have it rebuilt.

All the methods above just did not work! well, I know it's really really simple and convenient to exclude folder and files from validation in `MyEclipse`, yet I am using eclipse.
Could anyone help?

===============================UPDATE=============================

From this [highly-upvoted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131878/how-do-i-remove-javascript-validation-from-my-eclipse-project?rq=1) ,I add back the folder `common/js` and edit the exclude rule to be `*.js`, yet nothing happened.

The validation error I saw is on javascript files directly inside `common/js` folder.
[image: javascript validation error files]

Comment: That is *everything*, quite literally. What validation are you still seeing?

Comment: @nitind I had added a snapshot. These files is not written by me.

Comment: By removing the builder and disabling the validator, you've actually gotten into a state where neither can remove the markers any more because they're not running at all. Delete the Markers yourself using the Markers view. If they come back, then there's a problem to dig into further.

Comment: @nitind that's a good point.I will try it..