# Eclipse validation ignore pattern

Tags: eclipse

Is there any way to exclude files and folders that match a pattern from all validation in Eclipse?

In particular, I find that Eclipse frequently reports unnecessary errors and warnings for files in node_modules directories and would like to have these directories excluded from JavaScript validation by default for all projects.

This post explain how to exclude folders from validation but the instructions pertain to specific folders or specific projects.
[Exclude directories & subdirectories from validation in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495378/exclude-directories-subdirectories-from-validation-in-eclipse)

It appears the proper place to configure a default validation setting would be under Window -> Preferences -> Validators. I have tried updating the settings for JavaScript validators by adding new rules to an Exclude group with no luck. I have tried adding these patterns as a folder or filename rule:

```
**/node_modules
**/node_modules/*
node_modules/*
node_modules
```